# Imaplib on Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sockets, ssl, imaplib

Is there any way to support imaplib of python in google app engine.

I want to access gmail inbox using google app engine in python. The other way also exist to do this task. But I want it to do with imap.

I searched a lot. Reason why google app engine not support imaplib is that it not support SSL socket.

Any way I how to resolved it, Is there anyway exist?

Comment: You might check out context.io as an alternative way of accessing mailboxes through a web api.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tim Hoffman for pointing out the brand-new support for SSL in App Engine. The documentation for it is here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support.

EDIT: Unfortunately, sockets are only available for paid apps. (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/overview#limitations-and-restrictions)

If it's not too much I'd recommend that you buy $5 of App Engine credit till the feature comes out of beta. Then I'm pretty sure that they'll offer a free usage tier.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to access all users inbox for specific domain. I think if google app engine support imap then this link will be useful:http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough

Comment: But maybe you could access it as a feed here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed

Comment: In Gmail Inbox Feed we have to provide username and password, I want to do it using oauth consumer key and consumer secret

Comment: I also refer http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleAppEngine/2009-04/msg00986.html this link and get inbox feed, but don't know how to do same process for all domain users.It works fine for my personal gmail account.

Comment: Not true on the socket front.  As of 1.7.7 there is experimental outbout socket support.  So in theory you could get imaplib to work.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes  Though you need billing enabled.

Comment: Both of You are correct, I accept your answers. Any way exist without enabling billing for socket?